# Batch to find string and copy 1 line above and x lines below

Tags: batch-file

I have a 30,000 line log file that has several errors reporting in it. I am looking for a way that I can search out the errors and print them to a new file. I am hoping someone can help me with a batch file to achieve this. Below I will post a segment of the log file that has an error in it and explain exactly what needs to be pulled out.

```
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Date & Time:    5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Filename:       [sub_master_plan_new]
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Message:        Failed to export sub document. 
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Exception: Template fields are missing from the database: 
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[PlanComReg1] FM=[False]
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComRegion2] FM=[False]
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComRegion3] FM=[False]
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComReg4] FM=[False]
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Source: DocumentBuilder
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   Stack:    at NextGen.EMR.Documents.DocumentBuilder.Document.DocumentImportExportWizard.ExportDocument(TxTextHelper wordHelper, DocumentInfo dInfo)
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   
5/1/2014 12:13:26 PM:   END EXPORT: FILE[sub_master_plan_new]
```

First, I need the date/time section to go away. Next, each error has the text "Failed to export" on the second line of each error. I would need the line directly above the message "Failed to export" and any lines directly below the message "Failed to export" until the "Source: DocumentBuilder" line.

So the output should look  something like this:

```
Filename:       [sub_master_plan_new]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[PlanComReg1] FM=[False]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComRegion2] FM=[False]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComRegion3] FM=[False]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComReg4] FM=[False]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am unsure where to even start with this. Thank you for any direction that you provide.

---

My working solution: Thank you foxidrive

Download the two files that foxidrive linked to and use the below code to get the above results.

```
type errors.txt |repl ".*M:   " "" |findrepl "Failed to export" /e:"Source: DocumentBuilder" /o:-1:0 >> Output.txt

@echo off
Set "InputFile=Output.txt"
Set "OutputFile=Outted.txt"

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion > "%OutputFile%"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%InputFile%") do (
set s=%%a
>> "%OutputFile%" echo.!s:~20!
)

DEL Output.txt

type "Outted.txt"|repl "Source: DocumentBuilder" " " >"Output.txt"

DEL Outted.txt

type "Output.txt"|repl ":   " "" >"Outted.txt"

DEL Output.txt

type "Outted.txt"|repl "    " "" >"Output.txt"

DEL Outted.txt

type "Output.txt"|findstr /v /i "MessageFailed" >> ErrorsOnly.txt

DEL Output.txt
```

While extremely messy. It works. And that, in the end, is all that matters to me.

Comment: I am fine with vb also.

Comment: I would look to parse the file using Powershell.

Comment: Why does your sample output not include the `Exception: ...` line?

Comment: check, if `:   Filename:` and `:   Table=[` only occure on errors.  If yes, this would make it very easy.

Comment: dbenham that was in error. It doesn't matter if it is there or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses two helper batch file called `repl.bat` and `findrepl.bat`

download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat
download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place them both in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
  type file.log |repl ".*M:   " "" |findrepl "Failed to export" /e:"Source: DocumentBuilder" /o:-1:0
```

The above code returns the lines below.  See if it's of use to you or if you need more filtering.

Filename:       [sub_master_plan_new1]
Message:        Failed to export sub document.
Exception: Template fields are missing from the database:
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[PlanComReg1] FM=[False]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComRegion2] FM=[False]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComRegion3] FM=[False]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComReg4] FM=[False]
Source: DocumentBuilder
Filename:       [sub_master_plan_new2]
Message:        Failed to export sub document.
Exception: Template fields are missing from the database:
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[PlanComReg1] FM=[False]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComRegion2] FM=[False]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComRegion3] FM=[False]
Table=[ort_plan_comments_] Field=[planComReg4] FM=[False]
Source: DocumentBuilder

Comment: This appears to run but there is no output :/ Am I missing something here?

Comment: I got it using yours. I added >> output.txt to the end

Comment: Now I just need to strip the date from the beginning and all is well.

Comment: The sample data you provided didn't give me a date in my test.  Use one symbol on the `> output.txt` so it creates a new file every time with just the data from that run.

Comment: I got it figured out. :) I severely modified my "RunMe.bat"

Answer (score 0):

EDITED - I was missing the tabs. Code changed

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "filename="
    set "inError="
    for /f "usebackq tokens=3,* delims=:" %%a in ("LogFile.log"
    ) do for /f "tokens=*" %%t in ("%%b" 
    ) do for /f "tokens=1,2" %%c in ("%%t"
    ) do if "%%c"=="Source:" (
        set "inError="
    ) else if defined inError (
        echo(%%t
    ) else if "%%c"=="Filename:" (
        set "filename=%%t"
    ) else if "%%c"=="Message:" if "%%d"=="Failed" (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!filename!
        endlocal
        set "inError=1"
    )

    endlocal
```

The first `for` will split the line using the colon as delimiter starting at the third element (that will not be used) and retrieving the rest of the line. So the datetime part is discarded.

Then the initial tab is discarded and the line is splitted to retrieve the first element in the line to determine what kind of line it is. If it is "Source:", the error block ends. If it is "Filename:", store it to be echoed when the error starts. If we are in an error block, echo the line, and if the failed message is found, echo the stored filename and signal we are in a error block, so the following lines are echoed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Is this supposed to overwrite the old file because it just runs and nothing happens. :/

Comment: @Jordan, silly question but, have you changed the name of the input file in ther first for? file.log should be your log file

Comment: @Jordan, Sorry, my fault. I copied the lines in your errors list and i got  spaces instead of tabs (what i get when i edited the question just to be sure). Code changed to handle them.

Comment: I guess I don't understand this. It runs and looks like it goes through however there is no output. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
(
FOR /f "tokens=5*delims=: " %%a IN (q23427936.txt) DO (
 IF DEFINED $FTE (
  ECHO(%%b
  IF "%%b"=="Source: DocumentBuilder" SET "$FTE="
 ) ELSE ( 
  SET "$1=%%b"
  CALL :waitFTE
 )
 SET "$0=%%b" 
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
:waitFTE
ECHO("%$1%"|FIND "Failed to export" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :EOF
SET $FTE=Y
ECHO(%$0%
ECHO(%$1%
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q23427936.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt

Comment: This one is very close. When I run this against my log file I get a lot of extra lines looking like the  ones below.

Comment: END EXPORT: FILE[aud_patient_summary]
 START EXPORT: FILE[aud_patient_summary_jcmr811]
 END EXPORT: FILE[aud_patient_summary_jcmr811]
 START EXPORT: FILE[AUD_pedi_audiology_referral]
 END EXPORT: FILE[AUD_pedi_audiology_referral]
 START EXPORT: FILE[aud_procedurenote]
 END EXPORT: FILE[aud_procedurenote]
 START EXPORT: FILE[aud_rep_vng]
 END EXPORT: FILE[aud_rep_vng]
 START EXPORT: FILE[aud_report_balance]
 END EXPORT: FILE[aud_report_balance]
 START EXPORT: FILE[aud_report_template_cabr]
 END EXPORT: FILE[aud_report_template_cabr]
 START EXPORT: FILE[aud_report_vng]